# Is Probabilistic Reasoning In Intelligent Systems a pre-requisite for Causality?

Tags: references, causality

After having read *Book Of Why* and *Causal Inference In Statistics - A Primer*, I was reading *Causality* - all by Judea Pearl.

Yet I found that there were quite some points which I was not understanding. Particularly, Markov and Bayesian networks, axiomatization of probabilistic system using information relevance axioms, etc. However, having followed the references given to *Probabilistic Reasoning In Intelligent Systems* by Pearl, they were much more clear.

Hence, is *Probabilistic Reasoning In Intelligent Systems*, or parts of it, a pre-requisite of *Causality*? If yes, which parts might be good to go through?

Comment: In the same sense any book on related topic is…

Comment: See my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568281/is-there-any-theory-or-field-of-study-that-concerns-itself-with-modeling-causati/568294#568294

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have *only* read Causality (2nd ed) from Judea Pearl. I would say that, at a minimum. a graduate level course in probability and statistics is the only "pre-req".  I would say each of Judea's texts are intended for different audiences, rather than meant to comprise a didactic arc. Judea's approach in Causality is highly technical, and follows much the same line of reasoning as Rubin's Potential Outcomes Framework https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/016214504000001880. Judea and Rubin specifically develop an idea of causality as an "algebraic" concept, i.e. I can "do" anything conceptually. For a softer take that represents a different perspective, consider Hernan and Robin's book "Causal Inference" which I consider to be excellent https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/

Comment: I disagree. Without an understanding of Bayesian statistics and Bayesian networks, most readers would be lost in *Causality.*

Comment: Pearl himself has admitted his references to these networks in Causality are purely incidental. See related question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271103/what-is-non-parametric-structural-equation-modeling and his twitter interactions seem to suggest the concept is a work-in-progress https://twitter.com/yudapearl/status/1203502110286811136?lang=en

Comment: Not seeing the relevance in those two links.

Comment: @AdrianKeister in other words, you can develop a causal framework based on DAG by assuming WLOG that a modeling procedure exists for which the residuals for a particular node are conditionally independent of its ancestors (some combination of which are available as covariate inputs). Whether Bayesian, non-parametric, or parametric SEM turns out not to matter.

Comment: Well, that's very nice, I would agree. But you're speaking more from the perspective of someone already "in the know". I, for example, found *Causality* nearly unreadable because I don't have the prerequisites I have mentioned in my answer here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568281/is-there-any-theory-or-field-of-study-that-concerns-itself-with-modeling-causati/568294#568294), and I suspect many other readers would feel the same way. When I read a book, I am always driving towards "depth-first" or total understanding. Without Bayesian networks, I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: @AdrianKeister use SEM. And SEM can be just linear regression. Conceptually it's easy, and I managed to apply the concepts in a few of my publications.

Comment: Sure! And that would work for many scenarios. I don't think it would work for every scenario. For example: what happens in a scenario that requires the do-calculus? Pearl has an example of a causal graph where, to identify the causal effect, you must use the do calculus and you can't use any of the other tricks (backdoor, frontdoor, IV, etc.).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137938/discussion-between-adamo-and-adrian-keister).